# Would there be an invisible and unneccesary preposition after the word conjuntion "and" if earlier in the sentence there is already a preposition?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

I am trying to combine these two sentences in order to make it more concise.

The program provides training on reviewing data schematics; it also provides training on interpreting data charts.

I would like to know if both combinations A and B are both gramatically valid and correct. Thank you.

A) The program provides training **on reviewing data schematics** and **on interpreting visual data charts**.

B) The program provides training **on reviewing data schematics** and  **interpreting visual data charts**.

Answer (score 1):

You are offering a choice between two prepositional phrases using *on* joined by *and* (A) and a compound object of the preposition *on* (B). Both are grammatical, but B is better stylistically, as there is no need to repeat the preposition in a context where it’s unlikely a reader would forget that the second noun phrase is also the object of *on*.

If, say, you wished to modify *reviewing data schematics* with a longer relative clause, you might cue the reader that a second object is coming by inserting *both* after *on* or by repeating the preposition.